# convergence of $\sum_{n≥ 1}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})^\alpha(\log(1+\frac{1}{n}))^\beta$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would like to determine the convergence of the series for $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ What I did was to use the asymptotic equivalence that becomes evident, whereby
$$\sum_{n≥ 1}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})^\alpha(\log(1+\frac{1}{n}))^\beta=\sum_{n≥ 1}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})^\alpha\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^\beta=\sum_{n≥ 1}\frac{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})^\alpha}{n^\beta}$$
apparently, the expression is simpler but I don't know how I can determine the convergence of the last expression, any help? thanks

Comment: Use $$
\sqrt {n + 1}  - \sqrt n  = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {n + 1}  + \sqrt n }} \sim \frac{1}{{2\sqrt n }}.
$$ But note that you cannot write equality between sums after approximating the $\log$. Instead write asymptotic equivalences for the general $n$th term and conclude that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gary has shown, you can use $\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}$ to determine the convergence of the series. But there is another approach using Maclaurin expansion that can deal with a more general case that we will discuss later. Now let us have

$$
(\sqrt{n + 1} - \sqrt{n})^{\alpha}
= n^{\alpha/2} 
\left(
    \sqrt{1 + \dfrac{1}{n}} - 1
\right)^{\alpha}
= n^{\alpha/2} 
\left(
    \left(
        1 + \dfrac{1}{2n} + o\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right) 
    \right) - 1
\right)^{\alpha}
\sim \dfrac{1}{2^{\alpha}n^{\alpha/2}}
$$
And from here we have
$$
(\sqrt{n + 1} - \sqrt{n})^{\alpha}\log\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{\beta} 
\sim 
\dfrac{1}{2^{\alpha}n^{\alpha/2 + \beta}}
$$
Hence, the series converge if and only if $\alpha/2 + \beta > 1$

For the more general case, you can determine the convergence of
$$
\sum_n ((n + 1)^{\lambda} - n^{\lambda})^{\alpha}\log\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{\beta} 
$$

where $\lambda$ is an arbitrary real number. The idea is still use the Maclaurin expansion, you can try this for yourself.

Comment: What do you mean by putting $\sim$ between the two sums? There is no asymptotic parameter in them, they are just numbers for each $\alpha$, $\beta$ provided they converge. Their respective $n$the terms are asymptotic to each other for large $n$ though. You can solve the general version using the mean value theorem and therefore avoiding Maclaurin series.

Comment: Oops, that was my terrible mistake. I fixed it accordingly.